# custom class with default Typeconverter in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

Is there anyway to write a class

```
class A<T> {
   private T m_Val;
   public T Value {get; set;}
   // some methods
}
```

that can be used with `PropertyGrid` without providing custom `TypeConverter` ?
I know if the class overrides `ToString()`, `PropertyGrid` will display the class value, but the value is set to read only.

Comment: What's the problem with `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new A<string>() { Value="Some Value"};`?